# NPM: dependencies causing unwanted duplicate module instances

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, npm

Let's say I have modules `A` and `B` which both require a module `C`.

AFAIK, when running `npm install A` and `npm install B` I will get *two* copies of `C` automatically installed by NPM in module A and B directories - at least if those modules depend on *different* versions of `C`.

I expect that `require("C")` actually returns *different* modules for modules `A` and `B`.

What if `C` is meant to exist only once in a Node.JS process, like for example a database connection pooling module, locking mechanism or anything like that? Is this a known "problem"? How should such situations be handled?

Comment: It sounds like those modules should be redesigned so that the `C` dependency is passed into them both so that you can be certain that it will be shared.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a known "problem"?

It is a known **solution** for a whole set of problems. Usually, you're the one responsible for resources allocation. For example, you open a database connection and pass it (hidden somewhere in DB object) to all dependencies which need a database. Or, you're the one who starts a server which listens for HTTP requests on some port.

Otherwise, if `require("C")` would return one single copy of that module, it would be a nightmare. Imagine that A requires C version 0.1, while B requires C version 0.1.1. You'll either get an error, or will have to write `require('C-0.1.*')`-like requires all over the code. A nightmare.

Comment: I understand *why* the NPM/Node folks have chosen to deal with dependencies this way. However, assume a statement `require("C").executeSomeQuery(...)`. Assume further, that for some reason the connection pooling details should be hidden for the dependent modules (ie. modules A and B) and yet for `C` it may be important that only one, global pool exists. However, AFAIK the various `C` versions in the application don't know about each other. Do you see my problem?

Comment: I do see what you mean, but again, you're the one responsible for resources allocation. It should be in application code as opposed to a module code. It's up to you to make sure you're not creating multiple connection pools. Is there any special example you could share? Because DB is a bad one, you cannot just `require("mongodb").findAll()`. This statement needs a context: server name, authentication, database name, collection name...

Comment: well, it could be `require("mydb").init(<server>...);` once at first and then `require("mydb").doSomeQuery();` at any time in code, without needing to pass the DB connection around every time. Another example would be some sort of application-wide message broadcasting system (as an alternative to classic events), like `require("broadcasts").send("foo")` in module A and `require("broadcasts").listen("foo", ...);` in module B (say B supports A, but doesn't require it; A doesn't know about B; and app developer *shouldn't* need to care about). In large, dynamic projects these things come handy.

Comment: Sure, there are some disadvantages in this model. But having components doing stuff on their own... I'm not sure it's a good thing. As for your DB example - it's bad again. If `mydb` is your file and you use it within your app top namespace, it won't create multiple connection pools.